# Переместить блок вниз CSS

Tags: html, css, position

подскажите, как переместить блок `.rmenu` после `<P>` `.text_block`:

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="rmenu"></div>
    <div class="text_block"></div>
    <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rmenu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 990px;
    top: -2px;
}
.text_block {
    width: 100%!important;
}
```

То есть на css сделать так, чтобы блок `.rmenu` оказался визуально после тега `<p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content p {
  order: 1;
}

.rmenu {
  order: 3;
}

.text_block {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="rmenu">b1</div>
  <div class="text_block">b2</div>
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Как пример flex и order. 
Попробуйте с ним.

По вашему примеру совсем не понятно зачем нужен тут position absolute и нужен ли он тут вообще. Но если можно обойтись без него, то этот вариант подойдёт

Comment: попробую перевести в relative